# Linux virtual network for experimenting with zeroconf networking

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, dns, mdns

As a learning experience, I would implement simple versions of the services that allow [zero configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) to take place:

- Claiming a link-local IP address from the 169.254/16 subnet
- Claiming a link-local hostname using Multicast DNS (mDNS) to 224.0.0.151
- Announcing available services using DNS Service Discovery (DNS-SD)

On my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop, those services are handled right now by `systemd-resolve` and `avahi`.

How can I set up a virtual network on my computer to implement my simple replacements? Can I set up a virtual network interface that allows me to send and receive packets without them ever reaching `systemd-resolve` and `avahi`?